# how DOM distinguishes between the same element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

Question - I want to know how DOM distinguishes between the same element?

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Popper from "@mui/material/Popper";

export default function SimplePopper() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);

  console.log(anchorEl);

  const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    setAnchorEl(anchorEl ? null : event.currentTarget);
  };

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const id = open ? "simple-popper" : undefined;

  return (
    <div>
      {/* button 1 */}
      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
        Toggle Popper
      </button>

      {/* button 2 */}
      <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
        Toggle Popper
      </button>

      <Popper id={id} open={open} anchorEl={anchorEl}>
        <Box sx={{ border: 1, p: 1, bgcolor: "background.paper" }}>
          The content of the Popper.
        </Box>
      </Popper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In this code sample, there are two identical buttons but when I click on either of those buttons. The Popper automatically aligns itself according to that particular button (as shown in the images).[button 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGZEY.png) [button 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBPKz.png)

when I `console.log` `anchorEl` on either of the buttons, I get `<button type="button">Toggle Popper</button>`. so how does Dom distinguish between these identical buttons?

Comment: … they’re distinct elements on the page that happen to have the same content. How does a computer differentiate between two variables that both are set to 0? They’re information stored at different memory addresses. It’s how all of computer science works.

Comment: They are different elements... The onclick event includes `currentTarget` which includes information about the specific dom element that was clicked (offset position, style and everything else, like getting the element with `document.getElementById()` ), so the Popper knows where to be based on this informations.

Comment: Dig deeper; use `console.dir(anchorEl)` instead of just logging. You'll find differences.